# Square ID's change between API calls

Tags: square-connect

I'm currently in the process of switching my customers over to post Connect API changes (2016-02-16) and noticing some interesting differences in the data that's being returned when I call the endpoints using different credentials.

Using a credential prior to 2016-02-16 I am receiving ids in the form of UUIDs (eg 03a054e3-d842-41d3-79cd-52e5649730fb), using a credential created after 2016-02-16 I am receiving an id in the form of a random string (eg CDU56ZKBIUOH3JETZU6LOC35)

For those two examples I gave, they are the ids for the exact same item but using two different API credentials (one before the change, one after) so it'll good to know how I can convert between each id in order to match them in my database.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to item IDs?

Comment: Yes, Item IDs are going to be the first thing we tackle. Although I'm hoping for a solution that can apply to other API endpoints :)

Comment: It should only be different for items, and really it shouldn't be different at all. Would you mind emailing me at the address in my profile? I want to do some digging into your account.